# Google analytics with firebase not showing

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have firebase analytics for my app, works perfectly on the firebase site.
But when I clicked on View more in Google Analytics, it is giving me an error.

> You do not have access to the account, property, or view. Contact an Analytics administrator who has the Manage Users permission.

And I checked the integration in firebase project settings it says it is linked.
I see the Property ID there, but I can't find this Property ID in Google analytics...
I tried giving permission to Google Analytics property to the firebase-service-account and firebase-admin-SDK, I gave them an Analyst Role, but yet to be working.

when I create a new project for the same account it's linked easily.
What can I do??

Answer (score 1):

You need to have at least an [Editor role](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9305587?hl=en&ref_topic=9303569#zippy=%2Cgoogle-analytics) to the Google Analytics account/property, since your Analytics data now resides in the Google Analytics property, and not within the Firebase project. That's why you need to have matching user permissions in both Firebase and Google Analytics. You can use this [troubleshooter](https://support.google.com/analytics/troubleshooter/7264014?hl=en) to reach out to Google Analytics team and check how you can get access to the connected GA account in your Firebase project. You can check the GA account and GA property connected to your Firebase project in the Firebase Project Settings > Integrations tab> Google Analytics card.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue after moving organizations and changing permissions. I fixed it by going to the GA Admin settings -> Account Access Management -> and granting the **Firebase project {projectID} editor** the editor role, etc.